# Regex to check for 8 consecutive numbers

Tags: c#, validation

Usernames          Yes/No

1. “6789”           Yes
2. “33333333_TL”    No
3. “34567890-Shhh”  No
4. “123456-Hero”    Yes
5. “1234567”            Yes
6. “New12345678”    No
7. “87456773kk”         No
8. “1234567890”         No

Comment: Sentences don't magically become questions just because you add a question mark. What is your actual question here? :)

Comment: This is a statement, not a question (or at least rhetorical)

Answer (score 5):

See [Regex to check for 4 consecutive numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294626/regex-to-check-for-4-consecutive-numbers).

First check if your string's length >= 8 and then use a regex to look for N consecutive digits and if it finds a fit - your validation fails. Something like - /[^\d]\d{8}[^\d]/

Comment: I'm actually amazed you figured out what the OP meant... assuming you did this correctly of course. ;)

Comment: I would check the strings length is `>= 8` also before this

Comment: I agree, modified my answer.