# Regex for consecutive numbers

Tags: java, regex

I want to check if a number is consecutive for example:

12345 is consecutive but 54321 is also consecutive.

Now my regex I use only says 12345 is consecutive.

```
String consecutive = "^(?:0?123(45?)?|1?23456?|2?34567?|3?45678?|4?56789?|(5?6)?7890?|\n" +
                "         (0?1)?2345678?(90$)?|1?23456789?|2?345678(90?)?)$";
```

How can I change this regex to match the other one to? It must be for 5 digits.

Is there a better way then this regex?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better done mathematically instead of a regex?

Comment: Should after `9` be `10` or `0`, or maybe such case can't exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found regex to hard so I did it this way:

```
  public static boolean isConsecutive(final String pinCode)
{
    int [] digits = new int [pinCode.length()];
    int [] differences = new int [pinCode.length()-1];
    int temp = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < pinCode.length(); i++)
        digits[i] = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(pinCode.charAt(i)));

    for(int i = 0; i < digits.length -1; i++)
        differences[i] = Math.abs(digits[i] - digits[i+1]);

    if(differences.length != 0) {
        temp = differences[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < differences.length; i++)
            if (temp != differences[i])
                return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: you should remoce Math.abs()

Answer (score 4):

I don't think regex is the right answer to this question. It's possible, though (shudder!):

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(
    "\\b                                                       \n" +
    "(?:                                                       \n" +
    " (?:                                                      \n" +
    "  0(?=1|\\b)|                                             \n" +
    "  1(?=2|\\b)|                                             \n" +
    "  2(?=3|\\b)|                                             \n" +
    "  3(?=4|\\b)|                                             \n" +
    "  4(?=5|\\b)|                                             \n" +
    "  5(?=6|\\b)|                                             \n" +
    "  6(?=7|\\b)|                                             \n" +
    "  7(?=8|\\b)|                                             \n" +
    "  8(?=9|\\b)|                                             \n" +
    "  9\\b         # or 9(?=0|\\b) if you want to allow 890123\n" +
    " )+                                                       \n" +
    " |                                                        \n" +
    " (?:                                                      \n" +
    "  9(?=8|\\b)|                                             \n" +
    "  8(?=7|\\b)|                                             \n" +
    "  7(?=6|\\b)|                                             \n" +
    "  6(?=5|\\b)|                                             \n" +
    "  5(?=4|\\b)|                                             \n" +
    "  4(?=3|\\b)|                                             \n" +
    "  3(?=2|\\b)|                                             \n" +
    "  2(?=1|\\b)|                                             \n" +
    "  1(?=0|\\b)|                                             \n" +
    "  0\\b         # or 0(?=9|\\b) if you want to allow 321098\n" +
    " )+                                                       \n" +
    ")                                                         \n" +
    "\\b", 
    Pattern.COMMENTS);
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
```

See it [live on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/lH8oP1).

Comment: ♫ ...and a partridge in a pear tree! ♪

Comment: Some documentation needed.

Comment: @SuperUberDuper: Of course. Here is some information about [positive lookahead assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)) and about [word boundary anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) which are the only "nonstandard" features this regex is using. I hope this helps.

Comment: You sir are a regex pro! I bow before you!

Answer (score 2):

As many other commentators of this question I believe that this should not be done with regex. Regex is cool if you want to match repeating patterns of digits (like `111`), but not for arbitrary sequences of digits (like `123` or `246`). Since I was interested in the topic I wrote this code.
The input string may be **any sequence of characters** (digits mixed with non-digits) and **all consecutive digits of the given length** will be returned.

```
public class ConNumberParser {

    public static List<String> findConsecutiveNumbers(String s, int length) {
        LinkedList<String> matches = new LinkedList<>();

        // seek to first digit
        int i = 0;
        while (i < s.length() && !Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))) {
            i++;
        }
        // store the beginning of a consecutive series
        Integer matchedIndex = i;
        // and the direction
        Boolean increasing = null;

        for (i++; i < s.length(); i++) {
            final char c = s.charAt(i);
            if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
                if (null == matchedIndex) {
                    // first digit after other characters
                    matchedIndex = i;
                    increasing = null;
                    continue;
                }
                int difference = Character.getNumericValue(c) - Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(i - 1));
                if (Math.abs(difference) > 1) {
                    // no conescutive digits
                    matchedIndex = i;
                    increasing = null;
                    continue;
                }
                if (length > 2) {
                    if (null == increasing) {
                        // found first consecutive digit
                        increasing = (difference == 1);
                        continue;
                    }
                    final int expectedDiff = increasing ? 1 : -1;
                    if (difference != expectedDiff) {
                        // no conescutive digits in the right direction
                        matchedIndex = i - 1;
                        increasing = (difference == 1);
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                if (i - matchedIndex + 1 == length) {
                    // consecutive digits of given length found
                    matches.add(s.substring(matchedIndex, matchedIndex + length));
                    matchedIndex++; // move by one to keep matching overlapping
                                    // sequences
                }
            } else {
                matchedIndex = null;
            }
        }

        return matches;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String test = "A12345b321";
        List<String> m = findConsecutiveNumbers(test, 3);
        System.out.print(test + " length=3: ");
        System.out.println(m.toString());

        String test2 = "Ax.*1290134543b3210";
        List<String> m2 = findConsecutiveNumbers(test2, 3);
        System.out.print(test2 + " length=3: ");
        System.out.println(m2.toString());

        List<String> m3 = findConsecutiveNumbers(test2, 2);
        System.out.print(test2 + " length=2: ");
        System.out.println(m3.toString());
    }

}
```

Which yields the expected result:

```
A12345b321 length=3: [123, 234, 345, 321]
Ax.*1290134543b3210 length=3: [345, 543, 321, 210]
Ax.*1290134543b3210 length=2: [12, 01, 34, 45, 54, 43, 32, 21, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this one?

```
function test(r) {
    s = r.toString();
    if(s.length == 2) {
        return Math.abs(parseInt(s.split('')[0]) - parseInt(s.split('')[s.length-1])) == 1;
    } else {
        t = parseInt(s.split('')[0]) + parseInt(s.split('')[s.length-1]); 
        s = '' + (parseInt(s) + parseInt(s.split('').reverse().join(''))) / t;
        return new RegExp('1{' + s.split('').length + '}').test(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oops, I thought JavaScript. Please convert this to java.

Answer (score -3):

Does it need to be Regex? Off the top of my head you could split any incomming string into the characters, convert to a number and then check if b = a + 1 || b = a - 1 (setting some flag at the start to figure out if you are incrementing or decrementing.

---

**EDIT:**

The post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294626/regex-to-check-for-4-consecutive-numbers) might help you out.

This is the regex it suggests:

`/(^|(.)(?!\2))(\d)\3{3}(?!\3)/` (N.B. This is only for 4 characters)

Comment: This will match `X;55557*$P`

Comment: That other question is using "consecutive" to mean "X number of the same character with nothing else between", not what this question is asking for.  Actually, that question is a reasonable application for regex; this one isn't.