# Regex - Return Exact Number of Consecutive Digits

Tags: regex, vba

I want to return 5 consecutive digits from a string (working in VBA).

Based on this post [Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294626/regex-to-check-for-4-consecutive-numbers) I'm using the pattern `[^\d]\d{5}[^\d]`, but this picks up the single letters immediately before and after the targeted 5 digits and returns `h92345W`(from "....South92345West").

How can I modify to return only the 5 consecutive digits: `92345`

```
Sub RegexTest()

    Dim strInput As String
    Dim strPattern As String

    strInput = "9129 Nor22 999123456 South92345West"

    'strPattern = "^\d{5}$"  'No match

    strPattern = "[^\d]\d{5}[^\d]" 'Returns additional letter before and after digits
                                     'In this case returns:  "h12345W"

    MsgBox RegxFunc(strInput, strPattern)

End Sub


Function RegxFunc(strInput As String, regexPattern As String) As String

    Dim regEx As New RegExp
    With regEx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = regexPattern
    End With


    If regEx.test(strInput) Then
        Set matches = regEx.Execute(strInput)
        RegxFunc = matches(0).Value
    Else
        RegxFunc = "not matched"
    End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
([^\d])(\d{5})([^\d])
```

You can use this regex, the matched terms should be in the 2nd group

Comment: I get the same result "h92345W"

Comment: Are you selecting the 2nd group?

Comment: try to add matches(0).SubMatches(2) or matches(0).SubMatches(1), I'm not sure of the syntax

Comment: `RegxFunc = matches(0).SubMatches(1) '.Value`

Comment: Why do you use 3 groups?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a group:

```
"[^\d](\d{5})[^\d]"
```

And then the number will be in the first group. Not sure about the VBA syntax for grouping.

Comment: I get the same result  "h92345W"