# RegEx for very secure passwords

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am working on a project and need to validate password generation with the following rules:

- Minimum 1 number
- Minimum 1 uppercase letter
- Minimum 1 symbol
- No consecutive numbers
- Not include the email or username
- 8 digits minimum

So far I have a regex like this:

```regex
/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?!=.*\d{4})(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*(),.?":{}|<>])(?=\S+$).{8,16}$/
```

this only checks:
 - Minimum 1 number 
 - Minimum 1 uppercase letter
 - Minimum 1 symbol
 - 8 minimum digits

I am unsure on how to check for:

- No consecutive numbers  (4)

Accept:

```
1953
1749
7402
```

Dont accept:

```
1234
0987
4567
1111
9999
```

Comment: This site is English-only - please ask your question on [es.so].

Comment: Monserrat Genereux, did you get the impression that this is a site in the language you are using because you are reading it through an automatic translator? If you are so kind to answer this question, then I will in turn do my best to help you with learning how to use this community.

Answer (score 0):

Here some hints:

- How to check consecutive numbers: [Regex to check for 4 consecutive numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294626/regex-to-check-for-4-consecutive-numbers)
- There are more special characters `[!@#$%^&*(),.?":{}|<>]`
- I would do the other email/username as separate check, not part of this regexp. I would split email/username on `.-\s-_` and check if the password contains any of the splitted parts.

Also keep in mind that having very such specific rules for a passwords limits the amount of possible passwords. I would suggest adding a password strength meter instead of restricting and let the people decide.

Good luck!